# Gnome-Terminal: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused # Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:

Tags: gnome

Hi i'm trying to execute the following script and due to the gnome-terminal commando i'm getting the error:

```
 Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
 #Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

The script looks like this:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install maven
sudo apt-get install docker
sudo apt-get install docker-compose
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
sudo apt install curl
sudo apt install ruby
sudo gem install jwt
sudo apt install python3-openssl

##### Installation and configuration of components
sudo docker network create broker-localhost_default

#### Omejdn DAPS
cd OmejdnDAPS

### Get started
sudo docker build -t daps .

## Launch the component
if [ ! "$(sudo docker ps -q -f name=omejdn)" ]; then
    if [ "$(sudo docker ps -aq -f status=exited -f name=omejdn)" ]; then
        # cleanup
        sudo docker rm omejdn
    fi
    # run your container
    gnome-terminal --title "DAPS" -e "sudo docker run --name omejdn -p 4567:4567 -v $PWD/config:/opt/config -v $PWD/keys:/opt/keys --network=broker-localhost_default daps"
fi
```

I've tried

```
export=DISPLAY=:0.0
```

and

```
export DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority
```

but the error is still the same.

Does anyone knows another fix?